# Don't want Regular expression `on*` to match 'options'

Tags: php, regex

I have a lot to learn as far as regular expressions are concerned.

I have an associative array like so:

```
array(
    "label"=>"Special",
    "title"=>"Category",
    "onclick"=>"dosomething()",
    "options"=>array(
        "one"=>"something"
    )
)
```

I am trying to use `preg_match_all` on the array like so:

```
$match="on*";
foreach ($value as $param=>$text) {
    if (preg_match_all("/".$match."/",$param,$matches)) {
        $return.=" ".$param."='".$text."'";
    }
}
return $return;
```

My problem is `$return` ends up looking like this:

```
 options='Array' onclick='dosomething()'
```

Obviously, my regex is wrong. `on*` is not sufficient - It is matching '`options`' as well. :(

Can anyone tell me what would be correct regex to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're testing for "on" anywhere in the string.  You'll need to anchor the "on" to the front of the string with this:

```
/^on/
```

Cheers.

Comment: i knew it would be a simple correction. waiting on timeout to accept answer.

Comment: Actually `on*` tests for *'o' followed by zero or more 'n'* anywhere in the string. In regex `*` is not a simple wildcard character.

Comment: use . as a simple wildcard character. use .* to match any number of any characters.

Comment: From the return value you'll notice that "on" is in the middle of the string. I don't think this will match it.